# Join two tables with OR logic in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

As the title states, I am trying to do a merge of 2 tables. I want a nested joint where the values from the first table are always there and rows matching the second table are added to the first. I believe this is known as the nested join.

Unfortunately, it only allows for 1 key to 1 key matching where as I need it for 1 key in table 1 to 2 keys in table 2

Here is an example

```
Table1:

Group
..
..
Time
Date


Table2:

Group 1
Group 2
..
..
..
Other Info
```

What I want is where "Group = Group 1 OR Group = Group 2" and display the matching row from table 2 nested into Table 1

I looked at the following example but I must be confused by the syntax because it doesn't seem to be working for me.

[How to join two tables in PowerQuery with one of many columns matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54654147/how-to-join-two-tables-in-powerquery-with-one-of-many-columns-matching)

Comment: There is no way to join with an OR. You have to duplicate your rows in Table1 use an User Defined Column where row 1 = Group1 and row2 = Group2 - then join the both tables with this column.

Comment: I think I have worked it out. I played around further with the mentioned answer previously and got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further investigation of the answer post I linked earlier, I will add an explanation of it here:

```
Table.AddColumn(Source, "Name_of_Column",
    (Q1) => Table.SelectRows(Query2,
                each Q1[Col_from_q1] = [Col_from_q2] or Q1[Col_from_q1] = [2_Col_from_q2]
            )
)
```

So this did work for me and it adds an extra column that needs to be expanded to get all the values from the table. What i would add is that I don't know / haven't tested if there are multiple matches and how it treats it, based on nestedjoin, I would assume that it will duplicate rows in the first table.